# Adding a text control window to a wxMessageDialog box/AboutDialogInfo in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working with python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on Windows 7 OS.

In my app I have a about menu. Upon clicking the about menu I want to display some information about my app. I am trying to create a dialog box/AboutBox exactly as shown in the image below.(This is the about dialog of [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Click on `?` in the menu bar of notepad++.)

The special thing about the dialog box of notepad++ is that I need a text control window too. One can copy the info.

[image]

I tried to do the same in wxPython, but unfortunately I failed. I tried two different hit and trial approaches.

**1.** I tried to add the text control window to the <s>dialog box</s> wxMessageDialog  but it doesn't shows up at all.

**2.** I tried to use the [AboutBox](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#AboutBox) in wxPython, and tried to add the text control to it but it failed because the AboutDialogInfo is not a window and the parent of the text control should be of a window type.

```
Error:
    aboutPanel = wx.TextCtrl(info, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_controls.py", line 2019, in __init__
    _controls_.TextCtrl_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_TextCtrl(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: in method 'new_TextCtrl', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'
```

It would be great if someone could provide some idea on how to add a text control windows to a dialog box/AboutBox?

**Code:** Here is my code sample for playing around:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap

class gui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#fffaaa')
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(101, '&About1', 'About1')
        file.Append(102, '&About2', 'About2')
        menuBar.Append(file, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 101, self.onAbout)# Event for the About1 menu
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, 102, self.onAboutDlg)# Event for the About2 menu

    def onAbout(self, event):
        message = 'This fantastic app was developed using wxPython.\nwxPython is c00l :)'
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, message, 'My APP', wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        aboutPanel = wx.TextCtrl(dlg, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
        aboutPanel.WriteText('Experimentation is the part of our life.\n')
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def onAboutDlg(self, event):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        info = wx.AboutDialogInfo()
        info.Name = "My About Box"
        info.Version = "0.1"
        info.Copyright = "(C) 2014 xxx"
        info.Description = wordwrap(
        "This is an example application that shows the problem "
        "that I am facing :)",
        350, wx.ClientDC(self.panel))
        info.WebSite = ("http://stackoverflow.com/users/2382792/pss", "My Home Page")
        info.Developers = ["PSS"]
        info.License = wordwrap("Driving license and a AK-47 too :P ", 500,wx.ClientDC(self.panel))
        #    Uncomment the following line to get the error! 
        #aboutPanel = wx.TextCtrl(info, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
        #aboutPanel.WriteText('Experimentation is the part of our life.\n')
        wx.AboutBox(info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="My-App")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxAboutBox()` uses the standard about dialog for the current platform so it won't help you to achieve your goal. Similarly, `wxMessageDialog` is the native message box dialog which, again, can't have your custom text box. OTOH there is absolutely no problem with building any dialog you want using `wxDialog` and adding elements to it (and using sizers to lay them out).

IOW your mistake is to think that the class you need to use is `wxMessageDialog`: it isn't, you need `wxDialog`.

Comment: Just one more thing I noticed right now. In the image above you may notice that the text control has a title 'GNU General public Licence'. How to do that? I read the docs of TextCtrl, no clue there. I found from this tutorial that PageSetupDialog has this feature. Please check this link http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Common_Predefined_Dialogs  The PageSetupDialog serves an entire different purpose. :(

Comment: This is not part of `wxTextCtrl` but rather a separate `wxStaticBox` containing it.